# can we insert pictures inside a table in SharePoint 2010

Tags: web-part

I am trying to create a table which has my team members, their tile. I also want to add a picture in one column is this possible in SP2010.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you'd be better to create an image library and either link it to your team members list (or vice versa0 or add columns to your image library to accommodate the members details.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use a People Search results web part which will show the photos from SharePoint profiles.